# Let's get critical: Sep 2014 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Tor Stack Exchange](http://tor.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://tor.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Tor and viruses](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3697/tor-and-viruses)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Does Directory Traffic count towards Consensus Weight?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3813/does-directory-traffic-count-towards-consensus-weight)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can I verify my relay is working?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3815/how-can-i-verify-my-relay-is-working)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [What are the dangers of possible Mac OSX backdoor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3781/what-are-the-dangers-of-possible-mac-osx-backdoor)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Tor Browser Bundle: Are files downloaded using Tor?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3806/tor-browser-bundle-are-files-downloaded-using-tor)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Tor not opening certain webpages properly (symfony project?)](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3915/tor-not-opening-certain-webpages-properly-symfony-project)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Tor hidden service on Debian, nginx](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3729/tor-hidden-service-on-debian-nginx)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Tor will not allow me to view . onion sites](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3728/tor-will-not-allow-me-to-view-onion-sites)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 5)

---

- [I can't set up a hidden service, can anyone tell me what the problem is?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3921/i-cant-set-up-a-hidden-service-can-anyone-tell-me-what-the-problem-is)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Tor Doesn't Work Anymore](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3706/tor-doesnt-work-anymore)

**Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 5)

---